# Employees written up for discussing criminal history of a colleague

Tags: united-states, legal, new-york

Our company hired a new employee with a criminal felony conviction.  The employee came to work on their second day and told all of our coworkers about the conviction, making it common knowledge. Details on the trial are all over the internet.

Employees have been disciplined for discussing our new co-worker's past with other employees.

**Is it okay that our employer is writing up individuals for talking about our colleague, even though the information is now common knowledge?** Do those employees have any recourse against the disciplinary actions taken?

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: @dan-klasson Presumably, if it's discriminatory for the workplace to discipline its workers for talking about the new guy's felony conviction.

Comment: Yes, can an employer discipline an employee for discussing it if there was no  ill intentions and the employee with the felony divulged the information to everyone prior? It is my understanding that the employee who discussed it was simply voicing her concerns.

Comment: Where is this located? In what jurisdiction?

Comment: It was in NYS  (Oneida County )  and I believe the employee was only written up, no termination. The reason that she told me she received was because she could have put the company in jeopardy for a law suit for speaking about it because employees with criminal convictions have rights

Comment: @beaniebaby This depends so much on the specifics that it is impossible to answer. "Voicing her concerns" can cover a broad range, from making clear motivations behind decisions which she is supposed to take (e.g. distributing responsibilities) to things which actually are inflammatory, degrading, humiliating and defamatory.

Comment: What exactly do  you mean by "discussing" this could be for example "oh did you hear about xxx and their criminal past - you know you can never trust a **insert ethnic, sectarian slur here** "

Answer (score 1):

> Is it okay that our employer is writing up individuals for talking about our colleague...

"Okay" is unclear, if you meant "is it legal?" then yes, it probably is.

> Do those employees have any recourse against the disciplinary actions taken?

Maybe.
Or "No" if you mean legal recourse (though I Am Not A Lawyer; maybe I'm wrong).

I would tell them to wait a few days and then go to the person who wrote them up and point out that "Person X was telling everyone about the conviction. I realize that telling someone new about it may be inappropriate, but I wasn't revealing the info to anyone."

If they were telling someone new... they *were revealing* information and probably should drop it (and be glad they were only written up).